# GCP UI not displaying as it should

Tags: user-interface, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

I have taken a screen shot in Big Query (no data sets or tables displayed) but that isn't the only place I am running into this error. It even occurs in the support section which is aggravating yet amusing. I have reached out to Google several times but they have yet to get back to me - it's been over a month.

I personally believe it's something to do with my antivirus... Not sure.

[Screen shot of UI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kaphU.png)

Has anyone else had this problem, better still, does anyone know how to fix it?

Comment: Which browser? Open the browser debugger (Inspect), refresh the page and post the errors in your post.

Comment: Delete your comments and put the details in your question.

Comment: Got it working!!! Was my antivirus... Had to disable "Script injection into web traffic". Thanks all for trying to help.

Answer (score 0):

Tried to open the GUI of BigQuery on my Chrome browser and I'm seeing a display, what you can do is to try clear cache on your browser.

1. On your computer, open Chrome.
2. At the top right, click More More.
3. Click **More tools** and then **Clear browsing data.**
4. At the top, choose a time range. To delete everything, select **All time.**
5. Next to "Cookies and other site data" and "Cached images and files," check the boxes.
6. Click **Clear data.**

Another is try to use incognito from your browser.

Also from the suggestion of @John Hanley to open your browsers debugger and then refresh the page and post the error message on your post.